# Install R packages automatically from webinterface

Tags: r, ubuntu, package

In order to provide an easy way to extend my webapp with more packages i started thinking of installing R packages automatically by their filelink.

To keep things easy lets assume I have an input field and a button. 
The input field gets filled with a link to the package source (e.g. http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/C50_0.1.0-16.tar.gz). 
After hitting the button the package should be downloaded and installed.

I've found the required commands:

- downloading: `wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/C50_0.1.0-16.tar.gz`
- installing 1: `sudo R CMD INSTALL path/C50_0.1.0-16.tar.gz --library =/usr/lib/R/site-library`
- installing 2: `sudo R CMD INSTALL path/C50_0.1.0-16.tar.gz --library =/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`
- installing 3: `sudo R CMD INSTALL path/C50_0.1.0-16.tar.gz --library =/usr/lib/R/library`

Where to store these commands and how to call the script? (maybe exec in php?)

How to deal with the sudo? Is there a way to send the password through ajax etc or to avoid password requirement at all?

What do you think?

**EDIT (solution):**

Because I can't answer my own question for the next hours I edit my question with the solution I ended up with.

After some research and your hints I ended up with this code (found at http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-packages/ and customized for my needs)

**installPackage.html**

```
<%
cat(".Rprofile: Setting UK repositoryn")
r = getOption("repos") # hard code the UK repo for CRAN
r["CRAN"] = "http://cran.uk.r-project.org"
options(repos = r)
rm(r)

install.packages("packageNameFromAjaxCall", lib="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
install.packages("packageNameFromAjaxCall", lib="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")
install.packages("packageNameFromAjaxCall", lib="/usr/lib/R/library")
%>
```

**call with something like**

```
$.post('path/brew/installPackage.html',{package:packageFromInput},function(){
...
})
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `devtools` package?

Comment: What if someone wants to install their `rootkit_0.1.0.tar.gz` package?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta not yet. After having a quick look i can't see how `devtools` provide a solution for my problem.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That's why only me and the co-admin are able to install new packages. This feature is not for normal user.

Comment: Is there a reason to _not_ use `install.packages()` ?

Comment: I think if you install to a library in the user's directory, you won't need `sudo`.

Comment: no specific except it's the way my principal told me ;) Any other way is welcome.

Comment: @nograpes okay in this way there will be one problem less ;)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Okay i made a html file with `<% install.packages("Hmisc") %>` and put it into the brew folder (rApache is installed and working!), but the loading does not come to an end ... where is the mistake? apaches error.log contains this information `[core:notice] [pid 2557] AH00051: child pid 2563 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2?`

Comment: Thanks for your help, solution is appended to my question!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the User Defined Function to install and load required R packages silently. Hope might help. Here is the code:

```
# Function to Install and Load R Packages
Install_And_Load <- function(Required_Packages)
{
    Remaining_Packages <- Required_Packages[!(Required_Packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])];

    if(length(Remaining_Packages)) 
    {
        install.packages(Remaining_Packages);
    }
    for(package_name in Required_Packages)
    {
        library(package_name,character.only=TRUE,quietly=TRUE);
    }
}

# Specify the list of required packages to be installed and load    
Required_Packages=c("ggplot2", "Rcpp");

# Call the Function
Install_And_Load(Required_Packages);
```